# Euro 2016 Live at Gatwick Airport

Tags: airports, london, event-based-effects, entertainment, lgw

I will be at Gatwick Airport (North Terminal) during one of the Round of 16 of the Euro 2016.

Do you know whether there is any area there, showing live Euro 2016 matches?

Comment: There is probably a bar/pub/restaurant in the terminal that is showing the game on their TV. You can check out the airport's website for more insight http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/shopping-eating/restaurant-directory/

Comment: I don't think there's any probably here. The Euro 2016 will be on in every bar and probably most of the TVs elsewhere in the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wetherspoons pub after security has TV screens

https://www.jdwetherspoon.com/pubs/all-pubs/england/west-sussex/the-red-lion-after-security-north-terminal

and it's hard to imagine they wouldn't have it on. You could ring them on 01293 569874 to check.

Alternatively you could watch it over the internet, wifi and power info here:
http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/passenger-services/internet-and-wifi/

Comment: 'spoons normally seem to have Sky Sports News or Sky News on, rather than any actual sports channels. I'd say its worth checking.